# How to create an all browser support activex control installer?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-c++-2008

I have created activex control using MFC in visual c++ 2008.
As activex supported only by IE....
I want to create installer that can run my activex no matter which OS or which browser.

Please suggest me how to create an installer?

Comment: Do you have to have an ActiveX control? It will never work on Linux, iOS, Android, Mac OSX etc...

Answer (score 0):

ActiveX is only supported via Internet Explorer.  Depending on your needs, something like a pure HTML + Javascript website or possibly a Flash component might work.